# @RequestMapping without @Controller annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use @RequestMapping annoation in controller class without the use of @Controller annotation for controller class i will register the bean i am asking this coz @Controller class if i deploy as jar file it not working properly so any help ?

Comment: A code sample and a stack trace would go a long way in getting help with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need `<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourpackage" />` to activate annotations.

As for the question - your bean should be a controller in order to be eligible for request mapping.